# Expectation of a product of Brownian Motion.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Regarding Brownian Motion formula below, how does $E[W(s)W(t)]$ turn into $$E\left[W(s)\big(W(t)−W(s)\big)+W(s)^2\right]\;??$$

I have asked a question using the formula below, but this and that are totally different questions. Thanks for all the help!!

Assuming $t>s$,

$$\begin{align*}
E[W(s)W(t)]&=E\left[W(s)\big(W(t)−W(s)\big)+W(s)^2\right]\\
&=E[W(s)]E[W(t)−W(s)]+E\left[W(s)^2\right]\\
&=0+s\\
&=\min(s,t)\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Try rewriting one of the processes in $E[W(s)W(t)]$ and think of why doing so is useful.

Comment: got it... i feel so dumb. LOL thanks.

Comment: Don't feel dumb, just take the new knowledge you have and keep on learning.

Comment: @Patrick, Just to be clear, this doesn't necessarily mean that $W(t)$ is independent of $W(s)$, right?  If it did then the expected value would just be zero.  But, since $W(s)$ is independent of $W(t)-W(s)$, then we are able to take out the $W(s)$, right?  and if so, why?